# How to make Apache Nutch indexing while crawling

Tags: nutch

I started using Apache Nutch (v1.5.1) to index all the website under some certain domain.
There is huge number of websites (in the order of milions) in my domains and I need to index them step by step instead of waiting the end of the whole process.

I found this in nutch wiki (here http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial/#A3.2_Using_Individual_Commands_for_Whole-Web_Crawling) something that should work. The idea is to make a script witch calls every single step of my process (crawl, fetch, parse, ...) on a certain amount of data (for example 1000 URL) cyclically.

```
bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb crawl/seed.txt

bin/nutch generate crawl/crawldb crawl/segments -topN 25
s1=`ls -d crawl/segments/2* | tail -1`
echo $s1

bin/nutch fetch $s1
bin/nutch parse $s1
bin/nutch updatedb crawl/crawldb $s1

bin/nutch generate crawl/crawldb crawl/segments -topN 25
s2=`ls -d crawl/segments/2* | tail -1`
echo $s2

bin/nutch fetch $s2
bin/nutch parse $s2
bin/nutch updatedb crawl/crawldb $s2

...

bin/nutch invertlinks crawl/linkdb -dir crawl/segments
bin/nutch index crawl/indexes crawl/crawldb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/*
```

My question is: is there any way to specify this setting directly into Nutch and make him do this stuff in a parallel and more trasparent way? For example on separated threds?

Thank for answering.

**UPDATE**

I tried to create the script (the code is above) but unfortunatlly I get an error on the invert link phases. This is the output:

```
LinkDb: starting at 2012-07-30 11:04:58
LinkDb: linkdb: crawl/linkdb
LinkDb: URL normalize: true
LinkDb: URL filter: true
LinkDb: internal links will be ignored.
LinkDb: adding segment: file:/home/apache-nutch-1.5-bin/crawl/segments/20120730102927
LinkDb: adding segment: file:/home/apache-nutch-1.5-bin/crawl/segments/20120704094625
...
LinkDb: adding segment: file:/home/apache-nutch-1.5-bin/crawl/segments/20120704095730

LinkDb: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist:
file:/home/apache-nutch-1.5-bin/crawl/segments/20120730102927/parse_data

Input path does not exist:
file:/home/apache-nutch-1.5-bin/crawl/segments/20120704094625/parse_data
...
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(If I had enough rep I would post this as a comment).

Remember that the -depth switch refers to EACH CRAWL, and not the overall depth of the site it will crawl. That means that the second run of depth=1 will descend one MORE level from the already indexed data and stop at topN documents.

So, If you aren't in a hurry to fully populate the data, I've had a lot of success in a similar situation by performing a large number of repeated shallow *nutch crawl* statements (using smallish -depth (3-5) and -topN (100-200) variables) from a large seed list. This will ensure that only (depth * topN) pages get indexed in each batch, and the index will start delivering URLs within a few minutes.

Then, I typically set up the crawl to fire off every (1.5*initial crawl time average) seconds and let it rip. Understandably, at only 1,000 documents per crawl, it can take a lot of time to get through a large infrastructure, and (after indexing, the paused time and other overhead) the method can multiply the time to crawl the whole stack.

First few times through the infrastructure, it's a pretty bad slog. As the adaptive crawling algo starts to kick in, however, and the recrawl times start to approach reasonable values : the package starts really delivering.

(This is somewhat similar to the "[whole web crawling](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial)" method you mention in the nutch wiki, which advises you to break the data into 1,000 page segments, but much more terse and understandable for a beginner.)